# how to load nsnotification text from an array

Tags: iphone

I am wondering how its possible to load the text displayed in an nsnotifcation using an array?
I want the message shown in this notification to be loaded from an array and not for it to be a fixed text value.

Comment: By "text" do you mean the "name" property?

Comment: Are you thinking of a `UIAlertView` by any chance?

Comment: not neccesarily a UIAlertView, but the same thing can apply to a alertview, how would i set the message content to an array?

Comment: If my code worked, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what your question is asking, but if you have a NSString as an object in an array, you can access it by using:

```
NSString *yourMessageString = [yourArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

for example.

**EDIT:**
To set the alert message to the message in the array, simply do this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                     initWithTitle:@"Your Title" 
                     message:[yourArray objectAtIndex:0] 
                     delegate:self 
                     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                     otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

Comment: and by accessing this how would i set the message equal to the content of the string?